# Network manager doesn't find my wired conection

Tags: 10.04, network-manager

There is no problem to connect to my wireless network, but when I want to change it to wired connection the manger can't find the connection.

There is green light in the socket when I connect the cable. So how can I fix this problem?

I am using ubuntu 10.04 netbook version and my computer is a HP mini 2140.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Read these common guides on Ubuntu Documentation (10.04):

[Wired (LAN)](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/connecting-wired.html)
[Wired troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-lan.html)
[Wireless troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-wireless.html)

Answer (score 0):

green light in the socket is not the problem...it shows that the connection is correct and is ready to comunicate with the modem
type the following ccommand in your terminal

> sudo restart network-manager

then type the password

also make sure your modem turned on and ready

Comment: First thanks for your help, I did what you say but after the manager finish restarting it once again connected to my wireless network instead of my wired one

Comment: @assaf You configured your wired connection? means added the wired connection in network-manager?

Comment: No but I think that I don't need to because when I restart my computer every thing is fine