# Network problem in 12.04

Tags: networking, 12.04, asus, adapter

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 but when I run installer (or LiveCD) it writes that there is no connection to Internet (I don`t continue installation because ubuntu is the only OS on my pc and I need Internet access). Previous versions (10.04 and 11.10) work fine.
My network adapter is ASUS NX1001.
NOTE:I am loading from CD and run the installer.

Comment: check this question and run the terminal from ubuntu live cd (cntl+alt+t) then type the command sudo restart netwotk-manager http://askubuntu.com/questions/123539/network-manager-doesnt-find-my-wired-conection/123551#123551

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem yesterday when attempting to upgrade, for me it seems that the connection to the Ubuntu servers was too to slow for the installer to connect properly. Either wait a few days until the hype calms down or try waiting till later on at night (when I upgraded mine) when the servers are less busy.

Another suggestion would be to try and find the best server for you area by having a look at this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror). I found the second answer best as you can let the computer automatically choose the best server for your connection.

Alternatively you could download the .iso from the Ubuntu website, create a live CD or USB and upgrade that way.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Also i want to note that I boot from CD and run installer. And when I get "no connection, device is not ready" message.

Comment: At what point do you get this message?

Comment: I get it when i see the window where i need to chose between trying or installing ubuntu.

Comment: Does this occur when using a live USB instead of a live CD?

Comment: Unfortunaly my PC can`t boot from USB-drive so I can`t find it out. Also i have tried to change etc/network/interfaces by same file from debian (on debian network works fine) but it didn`t work.

Comment: Do you have any network access? Or is it just when updating?

Comment: I have no web access on Ubuntu machine. But I have same configuration with installed Debian 6.0.

Comment: It`s too late in my timezone for fixing it and I would better install Debian. Anyway, Thanks for your help!